# How to add multi-line header in PDF using iText?

Tags: java, header, itext, footer, multiline

I am using older version iText-2.1.7, can't use later / latest versions due to certain constraints.

I need to add multiple lines in header / footer. I know there are some posts on the same topic, but I couldn't find simple & clear answer anywhere, so posting it again.

I am adding header thru `ColumnText.showTextAligned` API currently -

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(
    pdfPageContentsHeader,
    Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
    phHeaderCenter,
    pageLeft + (pageWidth/2),
    pageBottom + pageHeight - TEXT_PADDING - (Integer.parseInt(header.fontsize)/2),
    0,
    PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR,
    ColumnText.AR_NOVOWEL);
```

Any idea what's the simplest way to have two rows there ?

Thanks,
Rajiv

Comment: I know the constraints that exist when using iText 2.1.7. They are described in the answer to the question [Can iText 2.1.7 / iTextSharp 4.1.6 or earlier be used commercially?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5) Summarized: due to constraints you can't use iText 2.1.7 anymore. I am very curious to hear about constraints in using iText 5 or iText 7. As already indicated in comments and answers to previous questions: you should not expect any support on iText 2.1.7 because it dates from 7 years ago. It's just too old.

Comment: Rajiv, the static `ColumnText.showTextAligned` overloads are convenience methods for single lines only, cf the JavaDocs *Shows a line of text. Only the first line is written.* If you want to add multiple lines, instantiate `ColumnText` and use it with a rectangle which can hold multiple lines.